# Groovy withBatch is really slow

Tags: mysql, groovy

I'm trying to use Groovy withBatch function and it's really slow (15 sec). I've tried with different batch sizes (10, 400 ...) and it always take a lot of time doing each batch.

It's the second query that I write with it and there are both slow.

Here's my code. Is there a bug in it or am I  using it the wrong way ?

```
static updateCSProducts(def conn, def webProductRows){
conn.withBatch(400, """
    UPDATE cscart_products p 
    SET usergroup_ids=:usergroup_ids,
        b2b_group_ids=:b2b_group_ids,
        b2b_desc_hide=:b2b_desc_hide
    WHERE product_code = :product_code
        OR product_id = (SELECT product_id FROM cscart_product_options_inventory WHERE product_code = :product_code)
""") { ps ->
    webProductRows.each({row ->
        ProductType type = ProductType.fromCode(row.type)
        String userGroupIds = type.getProductAvailabilityUserGroup().collect{it.getId()}.join(",")
        String b2bGroupIds = type.getB2bUserGroup().collect{it.getId()}.join(",")
        boolean b2bDescHide = !type.getB2bUserGroup().isEmpty()
        println row.id + " " + userGroupIds + " " + b2bGroupIds + " " + b2bDescHide
        ps.addBatch(product_code:row.id, usergroup_ids:userGroupIds, b2b_group_ids:b2bGroupIds, b2b_desc_hide:b2bDescHide)
    })
}
```

}

I'm using MySql as Database. When I'm looking at SQL connections, I don't really see any connection running a query while I'm waiting for the next batch.

EDIT:
I've removed the queries and it still very slow.
Heres the updated version:

```
conn.withBatch(400, """
    UPDATE cscart_products p 
    SET usergroup_ids=:usergroup_ids,
        b2b_group_ids=:b2b_group_ids,
        b2b_desc_hide=:b2b_desc_hide
    WHERE p.product_code = :product_code    
""") { ps ->
    webProductRows.each({row ->
        ProductType type = ProductType.fromCode(row.type)
        String userGroupIds = type.getProductAvailabilityUserGroup().collect{it.getId()}.join(",")
        String b2bGroupIds = type.getB2bUserGroup().collect{it.getId()}.join(",")
        String b2bDescHide = !type.getB2bUserGroup().isEmpty() ? 'Y' : 'N'
        println row.id + " " + userGroupIds + " " + b2bGroupIds + " " + b2bDescHide
        ps.addBatch(product_code:row.id, usergroup_ids:userGroupIds, b2b_group_ids:b2bGroupIds, b2b_desc_hide:b2bDescHide)
    })
}
```

Comment: There's indexes on product_code columns.

Answer (score 0):

You're running tons of queries on each and every update. You'd be better off retrieving a list of data and then looping over that. It's not `withBatch` that's the bottleneck, it's your implementation.

Comment: I've removed the queries and it still really slow. See update.

Comment: No, you still have queries in every single iteration... `ProductType.fromCode()`, `type.getProductAvailabilityUserGroup()`, etc. Those are all running queries behind the scenes. I suggest turning on SQL logging to see just how many queries you're running, you may be surprised.

Comment: No, those are an Enum and an accessor of a field in the enum. It doesn't go to the database.

Comment: If I comment this line, it runs really fast :  ps.addBatch(product_code:row.id, usergroup_ids:userGroupIds, b2b_group_ids:b2bGroupIds, b2b_desc_hide:b2bDescHide)